# Laravel API retrieve a single row from database using Vue.js returns blank page

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hi I am trying to get a single row from my database using Vue.js and API call, but I am getting the following error:

```
GET http://larapp.test/dashboard/api/article/ 404 (Not Found)
```

For some reason it is not getting the id of the article. I know that api route is returning a single article. I tried this in postman by writing

```
http://larapp.test/api/article/1
```

This is returning the row in json format. I am using resources in laravel to transform my model into a json object. This is my routing in api.php.

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', function ($id) {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return new ArticleResource($article);
});
```

This is my web.php routing. I dont know if the routing is correct, but when a user goes to /dashboard, the user will be faced with a single article. I have a view where I include the articles tag defined in my app.js and that is working (my vue component is being included in that view). How do i get the id of the user logged in? I am using auth in laravel to handle the authorizaton.

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id}', function () {
    $id = Auth::id();
    $article = Article::find($id);
    return view('pages.dashboard')->with('article', $article);
});
```

This is my Vue.js component. I dont if this is the correct way to list a single article from my DB. I have managed to get it working listing all the rows, but not a single row.

```
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            articles: [],
            article: {
                id: '',
                title: ''
            },
            article_id: ''
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.getArticle();
    },

    methods: {
        getArticle() {
            fetch(`/api/article/${this.article.article_id}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    this.articles = res.data;
                })
        }
    }
}
```

This is my app.js for anyone wondering.

```
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);
Vue.component('article', require('./components/Article.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Here is my view

```
@section('content')
    <article></article>
@endsection
```

Comment: *Is it wrong that /dashboard is in front of api/article?* Going on what you have written up, yep. A 404 means that the URL could not be found, which seems logical based on your routes.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the route I have provided? Because I did the exact same thing when listing out all the articles, but for some reason that worked. What about the ID in the article.vue? Is that provided correctly?

Comment: I think it's fetch(`api/article/${this.article.article_id}`). Change it to fetch(`/api/article/${this.article.article_id}`), note the forward slash in front of `api`. (Sorry for the bad markup, template string really mess with MarkDown formatting...)

Comment: I dont think that it is the error. Because it seems like it is not getting the ID from the article object.

Comment: Well, seeing as you're having a 404, I think that that's the error. Or at least it shouldn't matter that the ID is wrong/missing. That would give a 500 error.

Comment: The forward slash renoved the error! But still not getting the ID? Any suggestions?